# Obtener valor de una tabla usando la ID de otra

Tags: php

espero me puedan ayudar con esto que me está quebrando la cabeza.

Necesito obtener el nombre de la imagen de un producto utilizando la ID que ya está asignada en otra tabla.

El asunto es así:

Tabla 1: identificador, nombre, precio, descripcion, imagen.

Tabla 2: identificador.

Necesito que al momento de incluir el identificador impreso desde la tabla 2, el código valla y tome el nombre desde la tabla 1 identificando que debe tener el identificador indicado.

Tenía la siguiente función, pero esto no me está funcionando:

```
 function imagen($identificador){


    $consulta_imagen = sprintf("SELECT imagen from imagen_producto WHERE id_producto = %s", $identificador);
    $result_imagen=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_imagen);
    $total_imagen = mysqli_num_rows($result_imagen);



    return $result_imagen['imagen']; 
    mysqli_free_result($consulta_imagen);
}
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Considero que a tu código le hace falta más partes, porque no sé si ya hiciste o no conexión con `mysqli_connect` con tu servidor desde `php` especificando los parámetros de tu usuario, base de datos, contraseña y servidor, además de que noto que después de haber validado lo anterior, nunca estás recuperando los valores de tu consulta después de `$result_imagen` ya que para extraer datos necesitas alguna función como `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_imagen)` y así poder obtener un array asociativo con los valores resultantes de tu consulta.

Comment: "No me está funcionando" qué significa? Salen errores? Qué errores? No sale nada? Seguro salen errores en los logs. Por favor, sé más específico

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucioné solo... no era necesario hacer esa mezcla "cruzada"
solo debía incluir dentro de la consulta donde mostraba el resultado de los productos una nueva consulta..

```
<?php  
                $id_producto = $destacados['id_producto'];
                $consulta_imagen = "SELECT imagen from imagen_producto  WHERE id_producto = '$id_producto' LIMIT 0,1";
                $result_imagen=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta_imagen);
                $total_imagen = mysqli_num_rows($result_imagen);
            ?>
```